# need help with jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following HTML :

```
<ul class="someclass">
<li id="1">
<button type="button" class="grey"></button>
</li>
<li id="2">
<button type="button" class="grey"></button>
</li>
<li id="44">
<button type="button" class="grey"></button>
</li>
<li id="54">
<button type="button" class="grey"></button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now here is what I'm trying to accomplish with jquery :

When button is clicked to find out `id` of parent `li`, here is how I tried and failed:

```
$(".grey").live('click', function(){
alert($(this).parents("li").attr("id"));
alert($(this).parents("li:first").attr("id"));
});
```

Both give me `null` alerted, how can I do this ?

**QUESTION UPDATE**

Ah yes, I forgot to mention that this `button element` is not exactly in the `li` tag, its created on-the-fly when `li` is `hovered`, using `append`? I wrote this example just so you could get Idea what I'm trying

**ANOTHER UPDATE** :

When I try just `$(this).closest("li");` I get `[object Object]` alerted but if I add `attr("id");` I get null

Comment: This works for me. http://www.jsfiddle.net/kfKT3/

Comment: As long as it's inside the `<li>`, `closest` should work.  Try alerting `$(this).parent()[0].nodeName`.

Comment: @SLaks doesn't alert anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be an issue with your `id` values: you're not allowed to use tokens which start with a number. IIRC, Firefox won't mind, but IE fails on it (as it should). Change the ids to have a prefix, eg: `"item_44"` and it should be ok.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Excellent catch! I just tested in FF and failed to notice how the IDs were constructed.

Comment: `"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])"`

Answer (score 2):

[It works for me](http://jsbin.com/ipumi/edit).  **EDIT**: But not in Internet Explorer.  As others have mentioned, IDs cannot start with a number.  You should probably use a different attribute instead.

The best way do do this is to call the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
$(this).closest('li')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to me, though, since you're only traveling one level up, you only need .parent(), not .parents() ... but best might be .closest() (you can [read up on it here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)).